# Header file refresh/update

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble using header files.
I would like to "refresh" a .h file, in order to update all the values of the constants in it which depend on an extern variable (defined in the main .cc file). 
This is approximately the situation:

Header file (header.h)

```
extern int extern_value;

const int one = value;
const int two = value * 2;
const int three = value * 3;
```

Main program

```
#include "header.h"

int extern_value;

int main(){

extern_value = 10;

// Here is where I would like to refresh the header file.

// Here is where I would like to have my dependant constants
// (one, two and three) being updated.

return 0;

}
```

Please consider that this is an extreme approximation of the problem.
Do you guys have any idea about how to solve it? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is my actual problem:
I would like to have a header file which contains all the graphical constants that my project needs. They ALL depend on the size of the display. The first thing that the main program does is getting information about the display size; THEN, I would like the program to "export" this information on the header file, so it can calculate all the graphical constants relatively to the size of the display.

Comment: I can't help but think this is an example of a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question...

Comment: Does this even compile? [I doubt so.](http://ideone.com/YtBWoE)

Comment: Cant understand the problem's goal. Also its bad idea to have variable definition inside the header file, because it can lead to redefinition error as soon as you include header file in more than one source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. For a variety of reasons, but not least because your variables are `const`, and the expression you use to compute a value to be assigned to them is not continually re-evaluated.

What you want is to use [**functions**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Statements/Functions):

```
extern int extern_value;

int one() { return extern_value; }
int two() { return extern_value * 2; }
int three() { return extern_value * 3; }
```

Other notes:

1. You probably shouldn't have an `extern` variable for this. Pass `value` to the function instead:

   ```
   int one(const int value) { return value; }
   int two(const int value) { return 2 * value; }
   int three(const int value) { return 3 * value; }

   int main() {
       int value = 10;
       std::cout << one(value) << " " << two(value) << "\n";
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You can't "refresh" a header file. The content of the file is what you typed, and this is included (effectively, pasted into) the source file when you use `#include "my_header.h"`. You can update the value associated with non-const variables, but if you want to repeatedly evaluate an expression with different values, the best way is to turn that expression into a *function* as shown above, and call the function with different parameters.
3. You'll probably need to either move the function definitions from the header to a source file, or mark them as `inline`, otherwise you may be warned (or receive errors) about multiple definitions if you use the same header in multiple source files.

---

To address your actual problem, if you need to expose information through `extern` variables, you'll need to make them *non-const*, and have your `main()` function initialise them, or do so during static initialisation. There are a number of issues to be aware of when doing this, so it's much safer to provide functions that compute the geometry accordingly, and base those computations on one or two function arguments, or a small number of `extern` variables that are statically initialised to something safe, then set appropriately once the information becomes available. Further details can be obtained by searching for e.g. *static initialisation* or *extern variables*.

In this case, you may wish to consider creating a class to hold your geometry and perform the relevant computations. A pointer to an instance of this class can be created as an `extern` variable, and initialised on program initialisation (i.e. statically). You can then provide the derived "constants" as member functions which calculate their result based on a small number of encapsulated values, which can be set / updated if necessary. You can even make it such that these are `const`, if you're careful.

See, for instance the example below ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d11ec4b5ce0b6d8b)):

```
// ******** HEADER FILE ********

class Geometry {
  public:
    Geometry(const int rows, const int cols)
     : rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}

    int rows() const { return rows_; }

    int cols() const { return cols_; }

    int pixels() const { return rows_ * cols_; }

    // whatever other "constants" you need, defined as functions
    // containing expressions based on rows_ and cols_.

  private:
    // Make copy constructor & assignment operator private to prevent copying
    Geometry(const Geometry&);
    Geometry& operator=(const Geometry&);

    // The data from which everything else is calculated
    const int rows_;
    const int cols_;

};

extern const Geometry* the_geometry;

// ******** SOURCE FILE ********
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int rows = 80; // or however you get the number of rows
    const int columns = 25; // or however you get the number of columns
    the_geometry = new Geometry(rows, columns);

    std::cout << the_geometry->pixels() << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}

const Geometry* the_geometry = nullptr;
```